# Counter increase with new page

Tags: counters

How can I increase my counter with every new page and reset to 0 again when it comes to a new chapter?

I know that I can link my counter to a chapter so that it can be reset on every new chapter by:

```
\newcounter{counter1}[chapter]
```

but then I have no idea how to increase it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using [`everyshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi) you can increment the counter at every page shipout:

```
\usepackage{everyshi}% http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi
\newcounter{pagecntr}[chapter]% New counter pagecntr is reset with an increment in chapter
\EveryShipout{\stepcounter{pagecntr}}% Step pagecntr every page
```

This resets `pagecntr` to 0 on the first page of every chapter. [`atbegshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) could provide similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

One could also do it manually in the way shown in this example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent 0ex
\begin{document}
\newcounter{chapoffset}
\newcounter{chappage}
\setcounter{chapoffset}{0}
\setcounter{chappage}{0}
\newcommand{\newchap}{NEWCHAPTER\\\setcounter{chapoffset}{\thepage}%
  \addtocounter{chapoffset}{-1}}
\newcommand\mychappage{\setcounter{chappage}{\value{page}}%
\addtocounter{chappage}{-\value{chapoffset}}\thechappage}

                                       \newchap
Page \thepage\\
Chapter page \mychappage \clearpage
Page \thepage\\
Chapter page \mychappage \clearpage    \newchap
Page \thepage\\
Chapter page \mychappage \clearpage

\end{document}
```